# How to process CURL POST request in Express.JS when Content-Type is not mentioned

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, curl, post

I am sending the following CURL request to my node.js server. But when I try to extract the data, it shows it in a weird format, which I don't know how to parse.

**CURL Request:**

> curl -X POST -d '{ "url": "http://localhost:8000/event"}'
> http://localhost:8000/subscribe/topic1

**Data Output**

`{ '{ "url": "http://localhost:8000/event"}': '' }`

**Code to Process the Request**

```
app.post('/subscribe/:topic', (req, res) => {
    const topic = req.params.topic;

    /** Prnts a weird format of data !!! */
    console.log(req.body)
    
    let url = req.body.url;
    if (subscribeMap.has(topic)) { subscribeMap.get(topic).push(url) } else { subscribeMap.set(topic, [url]); }

    res.send(true)
})
```

And my express server is using body parsers like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Can you provide the data output?

Comment: @TasosBu hey my bad, I forgot to add the data output. 

The output is like this "{ '{ "url": "http://localhost:8000/event"}': '' }"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this option to your CURL request:

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Use it like this:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"url": "http://localhost:8000/event"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8000/subscribe/topic1
```

Comment: Ohh I see the issues. But I am not the one sending CURL requests. 

Can I process it as JSON when the user hasn't specified the Content-Type in their CURL request

Comment: @KunalGulati You can enforce this type of headers with `helmet`. One other option is to JSON.parse() the text of the body, but I would suggest you tell the people sending the curl request to use this header!